# Sending Php mail with attachement using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to do send PHP mail through ajax call, but I am not able to get attachments.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'php_sendmail_upload2.php',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function ( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
});
```

Is there any way to send mail with attachments using ajax ?

Comment: can you show us the code in php_sendmail_upload2.php, wherever the mail object is set. Attachments are to do with headers, would need to check that.

Answer (score 1):

Use phpmailer (http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/).  Make your ajax function submit to a php page that uses PHP mailer and sending attachments will be easy.